# Detect zoom on kendoChart

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-dataviz

I'm trying to detect if a user is zoomed in on a kendoChart.
The use for this is to see if I should refresh the dataSource of this chart.

*Code so far*

```
<!--DATA SOURCE!-->
var lineSource = new kendo.data.DataSource(...DATA...);

<!--KENDO CHART!-->
$("#Line").kendoChart({
        dataSource: lineSource,
        series: [{
            type: "line",
            aggregate: "max",
            field: "value",
            categoryField: "date",
            markers: {
                visible: false
            },
            tooltip: {
                visible: true,
                template: "#= category # : #= value#ms"
            }
        }],
        categoryAxis: {
            baseUnit: "minutes",
            labels:{
                step: 10
            },
        },
        pannable: true,
        zoomable: true
    });

<!--REFRESHING DATA!-->
setInterval(refresh1, 60000);
function refresh1(){
        if(document.getElementById("Line")){
            $("#Line").data("kendoChart").dataSource.read();
            $("#Line").data("kendoChart").refresh();
        }
    }
```

*Pseudocode for zoom detection:*

```
function refresh1(){
    if(NOT ZOOMED IN ON LINE){
            if(document.getElementById("Line")){
                $("#Line").data("kendoChart").dataSource.read();
                $("#Line").data("kendoChart").refresh();
            }
        }
    }
```

Q: Am I able to detect a zoom on the kendoChart?
Q: How can I detect this zoom for use in an "if" statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can detect like this.

var boolChange = false;

```
    $("#chart").kendoChart({

        series: [
          { data: [1, 2] }
        ],

        zoom:
      function (e) {
          boolChange = true;
      }

    });

    if (!boolChange) {

    }
```

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart#events-zoom